# unable to run function module when "fn main() -> ! {...}"

Tags: rust, embedded

learning some Rust here..

I am able to do this on command line!

```
// main.rs ------------
mod attach;

fn main(){
    attach::dothings();
}

// attach.rs ------------
use std::{thread, time};

pub fn dothings(){
    let mut cnt = 1;
    loop {
        // !I could blink a led here or read a sensor!
        println!("doing things {} times", cnt);
        thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(5));
        cnt = cnt +1;
        if cnt == 5 {break;}
    }
}
```

But when doing embedded, main can't return nothing

```
fn main() -> ! {...}
```

When using similar code! I got this error. (?the implicit return is ()?)

```
  | -------- implicitly returns `()` as its body has no tail or `return`
9 | fn main() -> ! {
  |              ^ expected `!`, found `()`
```

Any Idea on how to fix it?

Comment: I'm confused. Why are you trying to use the never type `!`, indicating that the function never returns, when it does return (after about 20 seconds)?

Comment: `!` means you need to loop forever, if you want to explicitly loop 5 times, then do that and add a different infinite loop after that.

Comment: As I read, when using this code in an MCU (without the prints, but reading sensors) it needs to have the "never !" on the main function! Please correct-me if I am wrong. I just want to put some logic outside the main function (in this case the loop). @loganfsmyth If I remove the loop count the situation is the same! Is there a way for the "dothings" function to return nothing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order for `main` to compile with type `-> !`, the body must be known to not return — and the body in this case is `attach::dothings();` You need to give `dothings` the same return type:

`pub fn dothings() -> ! { ... }`

You also need to not `break` the loop since otherwise it's not an infinite loop. This version will panic, which you probably don't want your embedded code to do either, but it does compile:

```
pub fn dothings() -> ! {
    let mut cnt = 1;
    loop {
        println!("doing things {} times", cnt);
        thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(5));
        cnt = cnt +1;
        if cnt == 5 {
            todo!("put something other than break here");
        }
    }
}
```